# Always check for screen on/off

Tags: android

To implement a simple sleep detection app I need to handle `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` broadcasts in order to get the timing related to user's sleep (based on device inactivity). However, these broadcasts cannot be put in the manifest; the receiver has to be un-/registered in some app component.

How can I implement that? It seems to me that registering the receiver in, say, 
a `Service` won't do much since after the service is done it should call for unregister. Unless I have a long, persistent service which is not doing anything.

Comment: "Unless I have a long, persistent service which is not doing anything" -- that is what is required. Note that users may not be excited by you taking up memory all the time.

Comment: @CommonsWare are there any resources on suggesting a better way to implement such service?

Comment: A better way than what? If you want to detect screen on/off events, you don't have much of a choice than to do what you describe, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `STIKY` service that is registering to a broadcast receiver.

In your broadcast check for on/off state in `onReceive` method:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
    // screen off
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
    // screen on
}
```

And register like this in your service:

```
YourBroadcastReceived receiver = new YourBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(receiver, screenStateFilter);
```

Don't forget to unregister after service is killed and always register just one time when service is created.